# Why does "x ^= true" produce false in this example?

Tags: c#, operators, logic, xor

Why does the statement z ^= true produce a false when the previous produces a true ?

```
bool v = true;
bool z = false;

z ^= v;
Console.WriteLine(z);

z ^= true;
Console.WriteLine(z);

OUTPUT
======
True
False
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because:

```
false ^ true == true
true ^ true == false
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor

Answer (score 20):

Because it changes the value of `z` in the first statement.

Answer (score 7):

^ Means XOR, XOR is defined as true if one but not both sides are true, and is defined as false in every other case.

So

z ^= v means z = false ^ true, which means true

z ^= true means z = true ^ true, which is false

**Note that ^= changes the value of the variable in the first and second statement**

Answer (score 2):

The truth table for `XOR` (`^`) is

```
a    b    a^b
0    0     0
0    1     1
1    0     1
1    1     0
```

The operation `lhs ^= rhs` is basically just a short-hand for `lhs = lhs ^ rhs`. So, in your first application of `^=` you alter the value of `z`, which (in accordance with the definition of `^`) changes the outcome of the second application.

Answer (score 1):

false XOR true = true, then you set z to true;
true XOR true = false, then you set z to false.

Answer (score 1):

An expression of the form `x ^= y` is evaluated as `x = x ^ y`

The result of `x ^ y` (XOR) is `true` if and only if **exactly one** of its operands is ***true***.

conclusion: *x ^= true* will produce *true* when *x == true*.